# Saving an entry doesn't add the ref to my other document?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a ProfileSchema that I want to keep track of posts that have been posted. When I save a new Post it has a Profile_id but when I fetch the profile entry the posts array is empty. How does this work?

Profile Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  posts: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'posts'
    }
  ],date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})
module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Post Schema

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'profile'
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema)
```

how I save it

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req,res) => {
  const newPost = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    body: req.body.body,
    img: req.body.img,
    user: req.user._id,
    profile: req.body.profile_id
  });
  newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));
})
```

I'm a bit confused the mongoose documentation uses syntax I'm not familiar with or haven't learned their way yet. my `user` populates when I fetch for the profile data but the `posts` array is blank when I populate it.